# What is the best way to remove a broken screw from a deck board?

Tags: repair, wood, screws

I used stainless steel trim screws (3 in x 9 gauge) to rebuild our deck and one of them broke off when I was driving it in. There was about a 1/4 of an inch left (just the shank, no head) but when I tried to twist it out with locking pliers it broke off and now there is not enough of the shank to grab onto with locking pliers.

Any recommendations as to the best way to extract it at this point? I've thought of cutting a slot with a hacksaw and using a screw driver, using an extractor bit, or using a hole saw and putting in a plug to cover up the hole that would be left.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need it out?   Have you tried drilling?

Comment: Can you remove the other screws holding the board down and pull the board up from the broken screw and then try the vice grips again?

Comment: The cause of that screw breaking off was not having a pilot hole of a suitable diameter or it not being deep enough. SS screws are not as strong as other screws even though they don't rust...

Comment: I could probably remove the other screws holding the board down and pull the board up and then try the vice grips again. I don't really have to have the screw out. When you say "have you tried drilling?" the answer is no. How do you recommend that I drill?

Comment: Another option might be to use a hand grinder and grind it down so that it doesn't snag anything.

Comment: Back to what DMoore said - why do you want to remove it?  Is it sticking up above the surface of the deck board?

Comment: Yes, it's sticking up just a little from the board and it could snag someone's foot or whatever. If I could grind it down so it's level with the deck board without damaging the board that would be an acceptable solution but I don't have a hand grinder. I do have some tin snips, though, and they might work. I also have a metal disk with a drill bit attachment for cutting through locks and I could try that.

Comment: **hole saw** - Definitely. Make a hole around it and (depending on how deep you can make the hole) either yank it out or snap it off. Then fill. Done.

Comment: As far as filling the hole, do you recommend wood filler or making a plug of the same size (using a scrap board) with the same hole saw and tapping it in place with a rubber mallet?

Comment: that screw is not coming out unless you first remove the board it's screwed through.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap grinders are cheap. Get one.

Before grinding, erect a shield to prevent sparks from hitting the windows or any other delicate surface (they will stick). Cardboard or an old blanket would be strong enough.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just pound them in further with a hammer. The first couple of taps usually flattens the top, then you can use a nail set to drive them in a bit below the surface.

Comment: Deck screws take a heck of a whack to drive, and it's even more difficult with a nail set.